# How to use transaction advisors with annotations?

Tags: spring, interceptor, transactionmanager

supose I have the following example:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    ...

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
    public TransactionResponse addMyEntity(MyEntity e) throws SQLException{
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And in my applicationContext:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Ok, now I want to add an interceptor after the rollback of the transaction if an SQLException is thrown. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I'll try to clarify what I'm trying to do:

I have a WS, that persists some information on a DB and returns a response (an isOk boolean and an errorMessage if something went wrong)

Whenever an exception is risen, I need to:

- Rollback the transaction
- Build the response with the error message and return it to the client.

It's like a try/catch around spring's transaction proxy

Comment: I already solved my problem adding a try/catch to the WS's endpoint. I forgot there was one more layer above my service. The endpoint is out of the transaction, so I can (and I now know that I must) manage the response in the endpoint. Nevertheless I'd like to know if there's a way to do what I was trying to do before.

Comment: can you show how you are defining your additional aspect? (xml and java code)

Comment: Please see in this link https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction

Answer (score 1):

Use the `order` attribute of `tx:annotation-driven`, and of the interceptor you will be using. Thus you specify which one runs before the other. See the [AOP AspectJ advice ordering](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) section

Comment: Thanks @Bozho, but I don't understand how I can define the joinpoint to do what I need to do. Please, read the EDIT update